# Is there a way to optimally index reversed varchars in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-indexes

I know that databases are able to optimally use an index for queries `WHERE x like "foo%"`.
But in theory, if you will reverse the text and store the reversed string in the index,
then that index could be used to optimally search `WHERE x like "%foo"`

Is there any way to create such inversed index in MySQL or any other database?

Comment: See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6751699/335858) for some relevant context. Long story short, it's probably easier to store a second copy of the string with its characters reversed, and doing your suffix searches through that auxiliary string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in MySQL 5.7 and beyond you can create generated columns and index them.

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE phrase (
  word VARCHAR(128),
  reversed_word VARCHAR(128) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (REVERSE(word)) VIRTUAL,
  INDEX worddex (word),
  INDEX reversedex (reversed_word)
)
COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

Then you can search something like this.  [Try it](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ibeDkM499grjn4BjGMmdUG/0).

```sql
SET @search_for := 'hello';
SELECT word FROM phrase
WHERE (     word LIKE CONCAT(@search_for, '%')
         OR reversed_word LIKE CONCAT(REVERSE(@search_for), '%')
      );
```

This can be quite a helpful trick for a general search feature. For example, if a users knows the last few digits of an account number this will find it.

Answer (score 2):

In theory (ie I haven't done this) the first step would be to create a derived column for the reversed text:

```
reversed varchar(128) GENERATED ALWAYS AS REVERSE(normal)
```

Then you would declare an index on it. I'm not certain MySQL allows indexes on derived columns (I know MsSQL does) but try it and see.

Comment: This column must be indexed for effective searching. So it can be defined as VIRTUAL - this will save the disk space because the value itself won't be stored in the table's data body.